# What bandpass Q factor do I want for 12dB/octave roll off?

Tags: filter, band-pass

Sorry for what may be a dumb question. 
I'm used to thinking about low and high pass filters in terms of db/octave (e.g. 6db for passive RC filter).

Whats the equivalent Q factor for a bandpass filter that would give me 12dB rolloff per octave in either direction from the centre frequency?

e.g. Fc = 150kHz
At f = 75kHz and 300kHz, signal should be 12dB down.

Is there a simple conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple?  Δf=fc/Q (-3dB BWp)

Q of 3 at fc = 150kHz gives ;

- 3dB  @  BWp = 50kHz max (27kHz, 76kHz)
- 6dB @ BWp = 77kHz max (  123kHz, 200kHz   )
- 12dB @ BWp = 193kHz max  (82kHz,  275kHz )

(using a model for linear phase Multiple Feedback 0.05 deg;   )

so maybe Q=3.1

***So what's all this Stuff About Filter Specs and tolerance error?***

*Maybe you want a flatter passband and and a steeper stopband?*

Then a Chebychev BPF staggers higher Q poles to make the ripple small e.g. 0.1, 0.5 or 1dB in the PassBand and thus higher Q yields steeper skirts in the StopBand.

*Maybe you want linear phase or maximally flat Group Delay?*

Like Bessel filters then using lowest Q staggered poles in the PB it minimizes excessive group delay in the pass band.

*Or maybe some other characteristic such as phase shift sensitivity or maybe stability with tolerance using 0.5% tolerance stackup or 5% tolerance parts..*

So the usual specs to define any simple filter as follows;

- Gain (Ao):
- Center Frequency (fo):
- Allowable Passband Ripple (Rp): [dB]
- Passband Bandwidth (BWp @ -3 dB):
- Stopband Bandwidth (BWs @ -Asb dB):
- Stopband Attenuation (Asb):
- Filter Order (optional): with -6dB*n per octave slope

More complex filters are defined by scattering paramters for input and output impedance s11,s22 and transfer function s21.

Answer (score 2):

The roll-off characteristic of a band pass does NOT depend on the Q-value.

At first - the Q-value Q=wo/dw is defined for the lowest-order bandpass (n=2) only (dw: 3-dB bandwidth). It is identical to the quality factor of the corresponding pole Qp=Q)

Secondly, the roll-off value does depend on the filter order only.
Therefore, a roll-off of 12dB/octave is equivalent to a second-order roll-off - to be achieved with a 4th-order bandpass only. (Note that we have a minuimum of n=2 for the most simple bandpass; the filter order is identical to the order of the denominator).

Comment: As you are asking for a specific attenuation at a certain frequency, it seems that you are mixing stopband attenuation and roll-off characteristics.